# How does one put a rectangular picture inside a round hole in another picture

Tags: layers, adobe-photoshop-elements

I have a picture where I have already removed an inner oval portion with the Quick Selection tool. (Am using Photoshop Elements 6.0). I'd like to insert another picture, which is a background, into that oval.

Am a rank amateur & have no idea which way to proceed. I have done various searches and also have looked through several YouTube videos, but have been unable to find the info I need. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you simply add the background picture on a new layer below the layer with an oval cut in it?

Comment: im unfamiliar with Elements but I presume as Android Hustle said use the layers pallet, what you need to search are for tutorials using layers and masks

Comment: Figured it out by trial and error. Used magic extractor under Image tab to remove center, then saved. Reopened PSE and put base pic as original and copy layer 1. Then added 1st pic as layer. Voila!! Problem solved. Thanks for above replies. Just needed the actual steps explained in detail. :-)

Comment: @11DeadlySins You think you could post that as an answer? It could be very helpful for other people, and that way the question won't remain unanswered. Answering your own question is encouraged (and it will also give you some extra reputation) :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it works in Elements as in PS. But I would try **Ctrl +** click on the **image of layer where is the oval** so u will get the same selection as is the picture and then make this the mask for the background picture.